# Place Cell Value in Subject Line of Mail

Tags: vba, excel

I generate an email in Microsoft Outlook from a ClickButton (ActiveX Controls) in Excel with code I found online.

How do I place a specific cell's value into the subject line (Cell M3 in my case)?

A number of codes I've found use "olMailItem", which my computer/network is having issues with due to the registry being corrupted; attempting to have that corrected but it may take some time.

How would I perform this function without using "olMailItem"?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer after additional trial and error; it has an arrow pointing to it below

```
Sub Mail()
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    '    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
    '    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    '        .Cells.Copy
    '        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '        .Cells(1).Select
    '    End With
    '    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "ron@debruin.nl"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line" & Range("A1").Value    '<-- addition
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```